# How to deploy JCA before WAR in Wildfly 10?

Tags: wildfly

I have JCA(jackrabbit-jca-2.10.1.rar) and example.war file deployed on Wildfly 10.1.0.
Here are config files:

**standalone.xml**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="jackrabbit-jca-2.10.1.rar">
                    <archive>
                        jackrabbit-jca-2.10.1.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/jca/DocumentStore" enabled="true" pool-name="RabbitAdapter">
                            <config-property name="ConfigFile">
                                C:\jca\repository.xml
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="HomeDir">
                                C:\jca
                            </config-property>
                            <security>
                                <application/>
                            </security>
                            <validation>
                                <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                            </validation>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```

In example.war file I have class which uses JCA repository.

**Resources.java**

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.jcr.Repository;

public class Resources {

    @Produces
    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/jca/DocumentStore")
    private Repository repository;

}
```

When I deploy it one by one, starting with JCA everything works good.
However if I restart the server I got sometimes following error:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jca/DocumentStore [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException]

It probably has some problem with deployment order. In my case JCA needs to be deployed before example.war.

I tried to add **jboss-all.xml** with following content:

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="jackrabbit-jca-2.10.1.rar" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

But still without success.

## I even tried to package it as .ear and set initialize-in-order to true, but still got this error.

**example.ear**

```
.
+--META-INF
|  +--application.xml
+--jackrabbit-jca-2.10.1.rar
+--example.war
```

**application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" version="7">
  <display-name>example-ear</display-name>
  <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
  <module>
    <connector>jackrabbit-jca-2.10.1.rar</connector>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>example.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/example</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

**standalone.xml**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="jackrabbit-jca-2.10.1.rar">
                    <archive>
                        example.ear#jackrabbit-jca-2.10.1.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/jca/DocumentStore" enabled="true" pool-name="RabbitAdapter">
                            <config-property name="ConfigFile">
                                C:\jca\repository.xml
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="HomeDir">
                                C:\jca
                            </config-property>
                            <security>
                                <application/>
                            </security>
                            <validation>
                                <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                            </validation>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```

But I still get the error:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jca/DocumentStore -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jca.DocumentStore

Does anyone know how to fix this error?